# __doPostBack reloading entire page instead of just the UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, postback

In my javascript, I have the following line:

```
__doPostBack('MyPanel', MyParam);
```

In my code behind, I use MyParam to query a database and bind the result to a gridview that's inside the MyPanel updatepanel. The updatemode of the updatepanel is set to conditional and in the postback part of the code I have `MyPanel.Update();`

The updatepanel works fine when I'm doing sorting and paging; only the panel is refreshed. However, when I trigger the updatepanel with my javascript, I see the traffic in firebug showing that the entire page is being refreshed.

What's the solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My assuption: your update panel is located inside the naming container, so its id in the client side will be a little bit different from the server side ID. This means you pass the wrong `__EVENTTARGET` parameter to the client `side __doPostBack` function and your partial postback became full(meaning not async).

So changing your client code to:

```
__doPostBack('<%= MyPanel.ClientID %>', MyParam);
```

should solve the problem.

BTW, you could get the second(`MyParam` in your code) parameter from the server side:

```
var arg = Request.Params.Get("__EVENTARGUMENT");
```

Comment: yes, the panel was not named properly. How do I distinguish from the sorting/paging postbacks from my custom postbacks. Yes, I can parse var arg but I'm wondering if there's another way provided by the framework. Thanks for solving my problem!

Comment: @frenchie: yep, there is another way to archive this - by implementing `IPostBackEventHandler` interface.